# Database query to get ordered item from the micro POS 3700?

Tags: database

-> First Place order

add 4 item in order

-> Remove (void) 1 item from the pos

-> still it reply order items with quantity X 3 of item of void...

now, how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This may get you what you need...
You'll notice that voids show up as negative quantities and negative amounts. If you were to group items in your sql appropriately, you could sum and get voids to cancel out the original charges.

```
   SELECT coalesce(Maj.name_1,'') as Department, 
          coalesce(Fam.name_1,'') as Category, 
          coalesce(mi.Name_1,'') as ItemDescription,
          coalesce(dtl.Seat,0) as Seat, 
          coalesce(dtl.chk_cnt, 0) as chk_cnt,
          coalesce(dtl.chk_ttl, 0.00) as chk_ttl
   FROM micros.v_dtl dtl with(nolock)
   left outer join micros.chk_dtl cd with(Nolock) on cd.chk_seq = dtl.chk_seq
   left outer join micros.emp_def empDef with(Nolock) on empDef.Emp_Seq = cd.Emp_Seq
   left outer join micros.mi_def mi on mi.mi_seq=M_mi_Seq
   left outer join micros.v_maj_grp_def maj on maj.seq = mi.maj_grp_seq
   left outer join micros.v_fam_grp_def fam on fam.seq = mi.fam_grp_seq
   left outer join MICROS.trans_dtl TRANS on TRANS.trans_seq = DTL.trans_seq
   where dtl.dtl_type in ('M','D') and 
   trans.business_date = '2015-04-23 00:00:00.000' and --business date of sales
   cast(cd.Chk_num as varchar(20)) = 000 --USE THE REAL TICKET # HERE
   order by dtl.chk_seq, dtl.trans_seq, dtl.dtl_seq
```